# writing to live.com calendar

Tags: html, excel, calendar, vba

I want to write calendar entries from an excel spreadsheet into my live.com calendar.

I am using VBA and have basically succeeded, I can write the start date and end date, I can add description, all fine.

However I cannot work out how to write the start and end Times. If I write the time into the .text it is basically ignored. If I look at the page being written the data-entry box vanishes and the time is shown as text but is ignored.

Can anyone help?

```
' GoToPage takes me to the right web paage and logs me in if necessary and sets HTMLDoc up.

GoToPage("calendar.live.com/calendar/calendar.aspx?rru=addevent")


HTMLdoc.all.Item("__livecal_id2").Value = Str(fromdate)

HTMLdoc.all.Item("ns10_startTime").Text = "16:00:00" ' doesn't do what I expect

HTMLdoc.all.Item("ns10_durationSelect").Value = "Custom"

HTMLdoc.all.Item("__livecal_id3").Value = Str(todate)

HTMLdoc.all.Item("ns10_endTime").Text = "10:00:00"

HTMLdoc.all.Item("ns10_whatField").Value = who

HTMLdoc.all.Item("ns10_saveButton").Click
```